# What Happens When Null is set to NSString??

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

What Happens when `Null` is set to `NSString`? and saved in `NSUserDefaults`?? Will it crash since it treats it like a deallocated instance??

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Do you mean `NULL` or `[NSNull null]`;

Comment: yes i have a sqlite db from which i am fetching, it returns a Null when i print it out , and then later after fetching from userdefault it shows -[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Comment: while printing it shows me (null) i dont know what exactly is returned from the sqlitedatabase

Comment: You can't do that.  It's meaningless to say "set Null to NSString".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing metaphors. First, sprinkle around some NSLog messages reporting on the object type, before saving then on retrieval (NSStringFromClass[obj class]). You did not make it clear if you are using a C based SQLite interface or Core Data with a SQLite backing store, so update your question.

Lastly, if you message an object of class A with messages that only class B responds to, you will get exceptions pointing that error out. A dealloced error is totally different, and indicates your memory management is faulty. To track down the latter error, enable Zombies and break on any message send to one (many Q&As on how to do that here).

Answer (score 1):

Now, if what you MEANT to say is "What happens when you set a NSString pointer to Null", that depends a bit on what you mean by "Null" (which is not a standard Objective-C term).

By "Null" you could mean either "nil" (which has C aliases of "null" and "NULL") or you could mean an NSNull object.

"nil" is a "null pointer" -- all zeros.  This means that the pointer does not reference any object.  "NSNull" is an object class whose only ("singleton") instance is used to represent "nothing", even though there is a real object representing this.

You can readily set a NSString pointer (ie, something declared `NSString *`) to nil.  (Note, no quotes around "nil"!)  This makes the pointer "empty".

You can also, with a cast, set an NSString pointer to point to the NSNull object, though this isn't commonly done.

(And, of course, you can set an NSString pointer to an "empty string" -- `@""`.  This is a real string of zero length, and is not really related to nil/null.)

Since "local" variables (variables declared inside a method) are not implicitly zeroed by the compiler when the method is entered, it's often good practice to explicitly set declared pointers to nil on method entry, so that, if they don't eventually get set (but do get referenced), they will not contain "garbage" that can produce mysterious errors.